# SQL Server 2008 math fail

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, math

After hunting around on various forums for almost an hour, I've come to the conclusion that SQL server is slightly stupid about simple arithmetic.

I am attempting to utilize a function which, until recently seemed to work just fine. Upon changing out some of the values for a different set of information on the form in use, I get the odd behavior ahead.

The problem is that it is giving me the incorrect result as based on an excel spreadsheet formula.

The formula looks like this:

```
=IF(D8=0,0,(((D8*C12-C16)*(100-C13)/100+C16)/D8)+(C18*D8))
```

My SQL looks like this:

```
(((@DaysBilled * @ContractRate - @ActualPlanDed) * (100 - @InsCover) / 100 + @ActualPlanDed) / @DaysBilled) + (@CoPay * @DaysBilled)
```

Filling the variables with the given data looks like this:

```
(((11 * 433 - 15) * (100 - 344) / 100 + 15) / 11) + (15 * 11)
```

Even stranger, if I use the numbers above (adding .00 to the end of each value) manually in the server environment, it gives me -11405.1200000000

With the values I am giving, it should come out  166.36. Unfortunately, I am getting -886.83

Here is the entire function and how it is called:

```
ALTER FUNCTION Liability
(
@ClientGUID CHAR(32),
@RecordGUID CHAR(32),
@Type CHAR(3)
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,2) AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ReturnValue decimal(18,2);

    DECLARE @DaysBilled int;
    DECLARE @ContractRate decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE @ActualPlanDed decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE @InsCover decimal(18,2);
    DECLARE @CoPay decimal(18,2);

IF (@Type = 'RTC')
BEGIN   
        SELECT @DaysBilled = RTCDaysBilled, 
                @ContractRate = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(ContractRateRTC, ' ',''),'$', '') AS DECIMAL(6,2)),
                @ActualPlanDed = RTCActualPlanDed, 
                @InsCover = InsRTCCover, 
                @CoPay = RTCCoPay
        FROM AccountReconciliation1
        WHERE @ClientGUID = tr_42b478f615484162b2391ef0b2c35ddc
        AND @RecordGUID = tr_abb4effa0d9c4fe98c78cb4d2e21ba5d
END
IF (@Type = 'PHP')
BEGIN   
        SELECT @DaysBilled = PHPDaysBilled, 
                @ContractRate = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(ContractRatePHP, ' ',''),'$', '') AS DECIMAL(6,2)),
                @ActualPlanDed = PHPActualPlanDed, 
                @InsCover = InsPHPCover, 
                @CoPay = PHPCoPay
        FROM AccountReconciliation1
        WHERE @ClientGUID = tr_42b478f615484162b2391ef0b2c35ddc
        AND @RecordGUID = tr_abb4effa0d9c4fe98c78cb4d2e21ba5d
END
IF (@Type = 'IOP')
BEGIN   
        SELECT @DaysBilled = IOPDaysBilled, 
                @ContractRate = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(ContractRateIOP, ' ',''),'$', '') AS DECIMAL(6,2)),
                @ActualPlanDed = IOPActualPlanDed, 
                @InsCover = InsIOPCover, 
                @CoPay = IOPCoPay
        FROM AccountReconciliation1
        WHERE @ClientGUID = tr_42b478f615484162b2391ef0b2c35ddc
        AND @RecordGUID = tr_abb4effa0d9c4fe98c78cb4d2e21ba5d
END
        IF (@DaysBilled <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnValue = (((@DaysBilled * @ContractRate - @ActualPlanDed)
        *
        (100 - @InsCover) / 100 + @ActualPlanDed)
        /
            @DaysBilled
        )
        +
        (@CoPay * @DaysBilled)
    END
        ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @ReturnValue = 0;
    END
RETURN @ReturnValue;
END
```

It is called by running a select statement from our front-end, but the result is the same as calling the function from within management studio:

```
SELECT dbo.Liability('ClientID','RecordID','PHP') AS Liability
```

I have been reading about how a unary minus tends to break SQL's math handling, but I'm not entirely sure how to counteract it.

One last stupid trick with this function: It must remain a function. I cannot convert it into a stored procedure because it must be used with our front-end, which cannot utilize stored procedures.

Does SQL server even care about the parentheses? Or is it just ignoring them?

Comment: -886.83 is the right answer.  Where do you get 166.36 from?

Comment: Keith, the 166.36 came from the excel spreadsheet I'd previously been using.

Comment: @user1854267, then something is wrong with the excel spreadsheet or the values you've been substituting into the equation. If you copy and paste your equation into [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%2811+*+433+-+15%29+*+%28100+-+344%29+%2F+100+%2B+15%29+%2F+11%29+%2B+%2815+*+11%29), -886.83 is correct.

Comment: @As Mr Quimby alluded to, this is order of precedence. Is 11 * 433 - 15 (11 * 433)  - 15 or 11 * (433 - 15). I personally never rely on it, and you can never rely on it when moving from one environment to another. So put all the parentheses in your worksheet and get the same answer, the use that in the sql.

Comment: You probably ought to pull the actual calculation into it's own function.  Also, see about getting the database corrected so that those rate fields are actual decimal types (why do you have a type for each?  why couldn't you just use a 'type' field?).  At least, try to put the conversion logic in another function, as well.  And the use of `@ClientGUID` and `@RecordGUID` - are those the actual column names?  If so, please "spindle, fold, mutilate" the designer.  Why is the table name `AccountReconciliation1`?  And what happens if they're getting billed for more than one type of work?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Except even (my copy of) Excel is reporting the correct (not the 'expected') answer with those values (actually, -886.8290909).  So, it's obviously still doing the operations in the right order.  But yeah, I agree, put all parenthesis in.

Comment: SQL Fiddle is [unsure how you got](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/6838) -11405.1200000000.  Maybe you have a typo?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse What's "right" in Excel is may be "wrong" in SQL, putting all the () means you are in charge not whoever wrote the code that evaluates expressions in each environment. I've been coding in different environments for so long, I put all my () without even thinking about it now. Even if I could rely on PEMDAS, I can never remember the damn rules anyway. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is correct, it differes of course if you are using float values 
instead of integers.

For (((11 * 433 - 15) * (100 - 344) / 100 + 15) / 11) + (15 * 11)
a value around -886.xx depending in which places integers/floats are used is correct,
What makes you believe it should be 166.36?

Comment: What is causing all this confusion appears to have been answered for me. The excel spreadsheet I've been using for some reason is giving 166.36 based upon the values given. The function works flawlessly on the other two sections of the form. Thanks everyone for your help. It looks like I'll need to look over the spread sheet very carefully.

Comment: @user1854267 - perhaps it's being formatted in some strange fashion?